# Highcharts column chart with additional labels in the middle of columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

My chart displays columns with min and max values:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: 'auto'
        }
    }
}
```

**[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8e0m2w5h/3/)**

How can I display additional labels with average values in the middle of the corresponding columns?

Comment: Do you want the datalabels to hold the average or the tooltip, or something else?

Comment: I'd like to display label with average value in the middle of the column.

Comment: Edit your question content to display the values **in the middle** of columns, not over. And change your title to adding **another** label inside columns, not over.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you, I edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **formatter** in `tooltip` and `plotOptions.series.dataLabels` and use **this.point.high** and **this.point.low** to get the high and low of the serie and calculate the average:

```
formatter : function() {
     var res = "";
     if(this.point.high == this.y)
     res += "Average: " + (this.point.high + this.point.low)/2 + "<br><br><br><br>";
     res += this.y;
     return res;                        
}
```

Here's the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8e0m2w5h/4/)

**EDIT:**

You cannot add another **dataLabel** in your chart. But, I managed to add the Average to one of your dataLabels and then using `jQuery` I changed it's position considering the amount of each average:

```
$.each($( "tspan:contains('Average')" ), 
    function(i, t) { t.setAttribute('dy', parseInt(t.textContent.slice(9))/135); });
```

Please see this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8e0m2w5h/5/)

Comment: I need all three labels: min, max, average.

Comment: Thanks Raeen, but this is not what I want. I'd like to display regular labels rather than poup tooltips.

Comment: If you actually see my edit to the answer and the demo, you'll see a label in the middle of each column for average!!

Comment: Thanks for solution, Raeen. Unfortunately I don't see labels in my Chromium but rather tooltip that pops up when mouse is over a column.

Comment: can I position an arbitrary label (not a dataLabel) somewhere in column? I.e. can I specify a label with coordinates inside of column?

Comment: The tooltip has the average value, but there are also datalabels on the columns that has the average. Check if you have errors on the page of the fiddle. There is also this property http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#labels which lets you put labels anywhere you want. But the problem would be when you resize the chart or the number of the columns change.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it's not supported. However, you can extend Highcharts, so you will render any text you want to. Simple example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/8e0m2w5h/8/

```
(function (H) {
    // wrap drawDataLabels, which will draw dataLabels when required

    H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.columnrange.prototype, 'drawDataLabels', function (p) {
        var x, y, series = this;

        p.call(series);

        // loop over all points to generate or update your label
        H.each(series.data, function (point, i) {
            if (point.dataLabel && point.dataLabelUpper) {
                y = (point.plotLow + point.plotHigh) / 2;
                x = point.shapeArgs.x + point.shapeArgs.width / 2;


                if (point.dataLabelMiddle) {
                    // animate dataLabel after redraw/resize etc.
                    point.dataLabelMiddle.animate({
                        x: x,
                        y: y
                    });
                } else {
                    point.dataLabelMiddle = series.chart.renderer.text((point.low + point.high) / 2, x, y).attr({
                        align: 'center' //align dataLabel in the middle
                    }).add(series.dataLabelsGroup);
                }
            }
        });

    });
})(Highcharts);
```